# How to flatten results of a table with two related "many" tables?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, pivot

I've reorganized some tables in my database to be more flexible but I'm not really sure how to write the SQL to extract meaningful data from them.

I have the following tables (somewhat abbreviated for a clearer example):

```
CREATE TABLE Loans(
    Id int,
    SchemaId int,
    LoanNumber nvarchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE SchemaFields(
    Id int,
    SchemaId int,
    FieldName nvarchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE LoanFields(
    Id int,
    LoanId int,
    SchemaFieldId int,
    FieldValue nvarchar(4000)
);
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Loans (Id, SchemaId, LoanNumber) VALUES (1, 1, 'ABC123');

INSERT INTO SchemaFields (Id, SchemaId, FieldName) VALUES (1, 1, 'First Name');
INSERT INTO SchemaFields (Id, SchemaId, FieldName) VALUES (2, 1, 'Last Name');

INSERT INTO LoanFields (Id, LoanId, SchemaFieldId, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'John');
INSERT INTO LoanFields (Id, LoanId, SchemaFieldId, FieldValue) VALUES (2, 1, 2, 'Doe');
```

The objective is to get a query that is flat for a loan with all its fields. (In the real world there will likely be between 20-30 fields for the same schema, but we just have 2 in the example):

```
LoanNumber   First Name    Last Name
----------   -----------   ----------
ABC123       John          Doe
```

I cannot use a pivot that references the 'First Name' and 'Last Name' because I'll have no idea what will actually be there.

I have a [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/340bb) with schema already in place.

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, but since it sounds like you want to change the query based on the schemaId, then you will want to use dynamic SQL.

If you had a known number of values or knew the columns for a specific schemaID, then you could hard-coded the query. A static query would be:

```
select loannumber,
  [First Name], 
  [Middle Name], 
  [Last Name]
from
(
  select 
    l.loannumber,
    sf.fieldname,
    lf.fieldvalue
  from loans l
  left join loanfields lf
    on l.id = lf.loanid
  left join schemafields sf
    on lf.schemafieldid = sf.id
    and l.schemaid = sf.schemaid
) src
pivot
(
  max(fieldvalue)
  for fieldname in ([First Name], [Middle Name], [Last Name])
)piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9be65/10).

If you had an unknown number or you want the columns to change based on a `SchemaId` that you are passing into a procedure, then you will use dynamic SQL to generate the SQL string:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @schemaId int = 1

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
                    from SchemaFields 
                    where schemaid = @schemaid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT loannumber,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select 
                l.loannumber,
                sf.fieldname,
                lf.fieldvalue
              from loans l
              left join loanfields lf
                on l.id = lf.loanid
              left join schemafields sf
                on lf.schemafieldid = sf.id
                and l.schemaid = sf.schemaid
              where sf.schemaid = '+cast(@schemaid as varchar(10))+'
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(fieldvalue)
                for fieldname in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9be65/13). Both of these queries will generate the result:

```
| LOANNUMBER | FIRST NAME | LAST NAME | MIDDLE NAME |
-----------------------------------------------------
|     ABC123 |       John |       Doe |      (null) |
|     XYZ789 |    Charles |     Smith |         Lee |
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern.  For more schema fields, just expand on the 2nd to last line with all the schema field names.

```
select *
  from (
    select l.LoanNumber, s.FieldName, f.FieldValue
      from Loans l
      join Schemafields s on s.SchemaId = l.SchemaId
      join LoanFields f on f.LoanId = l.Id and f.SchemaFieldId = s.Id) p
pivot (
    max(FieldValue) for FieldName in ([First Name], [Last Name])
    ) v;
```

If `SchemaId = 1` represents the fields for the `Loan` type, then you can also dynamically generate the full list of `schema field names` using something like the below.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) =
    stuff((select ',' + quotename(FieldName)
      from SchemaFields
     where SchemaId = 1
       for xml path(''), type).value('/','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
select @sql = '
select *
  from (
    select l.LoanNumber, s.FieldName, f.FieldValue
      from Loans l
      join Schemafields s on s.SchemaId = l.SchemaId
      join LoanFields f on f.LoanId = l.Id and f.SchemaFieldId = s.Id) p
pivot (
    max(FieldValue) for FieldName in (' + @sql + ')
    ) v';
exec (@sql);
```